# Git rebase into master and push without conflict

Tags: git, github

I have used rebase to "merge" a dev branch into the master which works fine. Now the master contains everything from the dev branch which is what I want. However, now I need to push it to github which keeps giving me conflicts. How can I push/sync to github and overwrite all the files there as well?

Comment: You can use `--force` to push but it's a destructive command and you will lose the history that exists on github. Please make sure you know what it does and use it at your own risk.

Comment: did you rebase the dev branch on top of master or visa versa: `git rebase master` or `git rebase dev` that will determine how you need to update your remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have rebased `master` on top of `dev`, yes, `master` "contains everything from the `dev` branch", but its history has been rewritten (hence the `git push --force`)

The correct sequence would have been:

- first replay `dev` on top of `master`:

  ```
  git checkout dev
  git rebase master
  ```
- Then merge `dev` to `master` (fast-forward merge)

  ```
  git checkout master
  git merge dev
  ```

In that case, `master` could be pushed without "conflicts" to its remote upstream repo.

Comment: That's ok, it's for a final project anyway and my group could honestly care less (same geos for the TA's) ;)

Comment: well if you other group members know about it and you did a forced push, you'll need to tell them to reset their branches. otherwise they wont be able to push changes.

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do to make sure that I have exactly everything on master the way other people see it and to bring in my changes from the dev branch:

First, make sure you have reference to the HEAD of your dev branch before any master rebasing or merging.

reset master to how it is right now

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

play the changes on dev as if they were done on top of the master branch

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

merge those changes into master (it will be fast forward merge)

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

send up those changes

```
git push origin master
```

If you force push as others have suggested, that is probably fine, but if others have references to those git objects that you overwrote with your rebase, then they will have conflicts when they fetch from that repo on github (so you will need to tell them that you did a force push). The general rule is to never rewrite history other people know about. So once you push to a 'public' remote its best to plan not to force push.