# What am I doing wrong when I try to rebase in Git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, rebase, git-rebase

I recently started at a new company where the team chooses to rebase new changes onto the develop branch rather than merging changes into it. I thought I understood how this works but I run into issues so often that I'm no longer sure I understand and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Typical scenario:

- I make a branch for my feature off if "develop".
- I commit changes to my feature branch. When it's time to merge into develop I've made 3 commits on my branch, and there have been 5 commits on Develop

  - I right click "Develop" in source tree and select the option to rebase my changes onto it.
  - there are no conflicts. The git diagram looks correct as expected except my branch says I'm 5 ahead and 3 behind now (the numbers from above), which obviously prevents me from pushing.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and every explanation I've read about how got rebase works doesn't seem to indicate that I am. The code on my side also looks correct and compiles.

Comment: Could you try from the command line?, and maybe see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111004/git-rebase-into-master-and-push-without-conflict#answer-21111303

Comment: It's probably better to rebase onto `origin/develop`.  `develop` is a local branch, it's wherever your last local work on that branch left it; `origin/develop` is whatever that branch was on the `origin` repo last your repos talked, whether that's fetch or push or one of the convenience ops that include a fetch, like clone or pull.

Comment: Rebasing will always say “# behind, # ahead” if you already pushed. You’re changing the history.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think this is the answer. So in order to rebase I have to have not pushed my commits yet. That makes sense

Comment: Well you can rebase whenever, but if you’ve already pushed that branch you’ll need to force push the rebased update.

Comment: @evolutionxbox this was definitely my issue. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 3):

The "Develop" branch on which  you rebased your feature may not be the most recent one.

You have to first update your local Develop branch (`git checkout develop; git pull`), then rebase your feature branch onto it (`git checkout feature; git rebase develop`), and then you should be able to push it to the remote directory.